# How can I make this code shorter and more correct? (searching and copying files)

Tags: bash

This code searches and recursively copies the files after the above date.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=~/somefolder
DAYSAGO=8

for ((a=0; a <= DAYSAGO ; a++))
do
    find $directory -mtime $a -type f | while read file; 
    do
        cp "$file" -t ~/The\ other\ folder/
    done
done
```

Comment: BTW, in the future, for feedback on already-working code, consider Code Review StackExchange instead. This type of question is often considered "too broad" on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

directory=~/'somefolder'
DAYSAGO=8

find "$directory" -mtime -$(( DAYSAGO + 1 )) -type f -exec cp -t ~/'The other folder'/ {} +
```

- Using `-` to prefix the `-mtime` argument applies *less-than* logic to the argument value. *All* `find` tests that take numeric arguments support this logic (and its counterpart, `+`, for *more-than* logic). <sup>Tip of the hat to [miracle 173](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754550/miracle173).</sup>

  - Since the desired logic is `<= $DAYSAGO`, `1` is added using an arithmetic expansion (`$(( ... ))`), to achieve the desired logic (needless to say, `$DAYSAGO` could be redefined with less-than logic in mind, to `9`, so as to make the arithmetic expansion unnecessary).
- Using `-exec` with the `+` terminator invokes the specified command with (typically) *all* matching filenames *at once*, which is much more efficient than piping to a shell loop.
- `{}` is the placeholder for the list of matching filenames, and note that with `+` it *must* be the *last* argument before the `+` terminator (by contrast, with the invoke-once-for-*each*-matching-file terminator `\;`, the `{}` can be placed anywhere).

  - Note that the command above therefore only works with `cp` implementations that support the `-t` option, which allows placing the target directory *first*,  notably, *GNU* `cp` (BSD/OSX `cp` and the POSIX specification, by contrast, do NOT support `-t`).
- Also note the changes in quoting:

  - `directory=~/'somefolder'`: single-quoting literal `somefolder` - while not strictly necessary in this particular case - ensures that the enclosed name works even if it contains embedded spaces or other shell metacharacters.

    - Note, however, that the `~/` part *must* remain *unquoted* for the `~` to expand to the current user's home dir.
  - `"$directory"`: double-quoting the variable reference ensures that its value is not interpreted further by the shell, making it safe to use paths with embedded whitespace and other shell metacharacters.
  - `~/'The other folder'/` provides a more legible alternative to `~/The\ other\ folder/` (and is also easier to type), demonstrating the same mix of unquoted and quoted parts as above.

Comment: I like my explanation better, but this suggests a better usage of `-exec`, using `+` to copy as many files as possible at a time.

Comment: I don't understand the while loop, I think .mtime -$DAYSAGO will cover the whole range.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner. I hadn't gotten around to an explanation yet - added now.

Comment: @user3439894: Fair point in general, and I've updated it to `directory=~/'somefolder'` to make it more robust. Your suggestions, however, would not work, because the `~` must be _unquoted_ (and, if followed by more characters, must be followed by an unquoted `/`) in order for `~` to expand to the home dir.

Comment: @mklement0, Yes, was on the right track but forgot that `~` need to be expanded. Thanks.

Comment: @miracle173: You are absolutely correct - I missed that - will update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `while` loop at all. Using it as you are exposes you to problems with some corner cases like filenames containing newlines and other whitespace. Just use the `-exec` primary.

```
find "$directory" -mtime "$a" -type f -exec cp {} -t ~/The\ other\ folder/ \;
```

UPDATE: use [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343906/1126841), though; it's more efficient.